# Conditionally send email from contact form with different variables

Tags: php, forms, email, conditional-statements

I have a contact form that has certain conditions. If the user clicks the radio button saying they are a Consumer, a new range of questions appears. If they click that they have an image to upload, the image uploader appears.

As it is now, the email that is sent to us and to the user shows all of the fields, even if blank. It has the potential to get confusing if the person didn't click that they were a consumer, only to see 3 extra questions in their email confirmation that they didn't even see on the form.

I have it set up so there is a $success that should send the message to us and the user without all of the consumer questions, $successConsumer that should send the message to us and the user with consumer questions, but without the image, and $successOther that should send the message to us and the user with consumer questions AND the image.

I have tried including the variable in with the if statements, i.e

```
if ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] == 0) {
     $successOther = mail($email_address, $subject, $messageOther, $headers);
     $successOther = mail($email_address, $subject, $messageOther2, $headers);
     header("Location: thanks.php");
    }
```

with no luck, as well as using eval(), return(), and exit() in similar fashions. It either doesn't work at all, or it will send me all 6 messages, not just 2. I'm sure there is a way to do this, but I'm just not grasping how it's done. I've tried multiple Google searches, but I'm coming up with nothing. Any help or direction is really appreciated!

```
<?php
//Collect contact form data
//Check Special Field
//Email ASC & Webmaster
//Email Sender
//Redirect to thank you page

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/includes/functions.php');



/********  CONTACT DATA **********/
$name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
$company = stripslashes($_POST['company']);
$address = stripslashes($_POST['address']);
$city = stripslashes($_POST['city']);
$state = stripslashes($_POST['state']);
$zipcode = stripslashes($_POST['zipcode']);
$country = stripslashes($_POST['country']);
$website = $_POST['website'];
$phone = stripslashes($_POST['phone']);
$fax = stripslashes($_POST['fax']);
$email = stripslashes($_POST['contact']);
$Referred = stripslashes($_POST['referred']);
$CustomerType = stripslashes($_POST['CustomerType']);
$Comments = stripslashes($_POST['comments']);
$ConsumerHelp = stripslashes($_POST['ConsumerHelp']);
$UPC = stripslashes($_POST['UPC']);
$uploaded_file = ($_FILES['uploaded_file']);


if ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] == 0) {

     header("Location: thanks.php");
    }

else {
   // there is a file
    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);
    $userImage = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"];
    $location = str_replace(' ', '_', $location);
    if ((($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "image/jpg"))
    && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] < 2300000 )
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["error"] . "<br>";
      } else {
        header("Location: thanks.php");

        if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"])) {
          echo $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        } else {

         $location = "uploads/" . $temp[0].".".time().".".$extension;
         $location = str_replace(' ', '_', $location);
         move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"], $location);
         echo "Stored in: " . $location;
        }
      }
    } else {
      header("Location: sorry.php");
        exit ();
    }
}


    /******** NOT CONSUMER  EMAIL ASC & WEBMASTER  **********/
    $message = "
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Information Inquiry
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

$name has visited the web site and would like some information.
The details they entered on the website are:

Name: $name
Company: $company
Address: $address
City: $city
State: $state
Zip Code: $zipcode
Country: $country
Website: $website
Phone: $phone
Fax: $fax
Email: $email

Referred to web site: $Referred

CustomerType: $CustomerType

Comments: $Comments

I need help with: $ConsumerHelp

UPC code or Item #: $UPC

Image: http://www.example.com/test/$location
        (If the consumer sent the form without attaching an image, the link above will not have the file name at the end - just ignore it.)

Kind Regards,

";
    $email_address = "example@example.com";

    $subject = "Information Inquiry";
    $headers = "From: $name <$email>";
    $message = str_replace("\r",'',$message); //fixes postfix php bug that double spaces messages





    /******** NOT CONSUMER  EMAIL SENDER **********/
    $message2 = "
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Re: Information Inquiry
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Thank you $name for visiting the web site. We will be using the details you entered to contact you.

Name: $name
Company: $company
Address: $address
City: $city
State: $state
Zip Code: $zipcode
Country: $country
Website: $website
Phone: $phone
Fax: $fax
Email: $email

Referred to web site: $Referred

CustomerType: $CustomerType

Comments: $Comments

I need help with: $ConsumerHelp

UPC code or Item #: $UPC

Image: $userImage

Kind Regards,

";
    $email_address2 = "$email";
    $subject2 = "Re: Information Inquiry";
    $headers2 = "From: Example <example@example.com>";
    $message2 = str_replace("\r",'',$message2); //fixes postfix php bug that double spaces messages


    /******** CONSUMER - WITH IMAGE - EMAIL ASC & WEBMASTER  **********/
    $messageConsumer = "
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Information Inquiry
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

$name has visited the  web site and would like some information.
The details they entered on the website are:

Name: $name
Company: $company
Address: $address
City: $city
State: $state
Zip Code: $zipcode
Country: $country
Website: $website
Phone: $phone
Fax: $fax
Email: $email

Referred to web site: $Referred

CustomerType: $CustomerType

Comments: $Comments

I need help with: $ConsumerHelp

UPC code or Item #: $UPC

Image: http://www.example.com/test/$location

Kind Regards,

";
    $email_address = "example@example.com";

    $subject = "Information Inquiry";
    $headers = "From: $name <$email>";
    $messageConsumer = str_replace("\r",'',$messageConsumer); //fixes postfix php bug that double spaces messages





    /********  CONSUMER - WITH IMAGE - EMAIL SENDER **********/
    $messageConsumer2 = "
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Re: Information Inquiry
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Thank you $name for visiting the web site. We will be using the details you entered to contact you.

Name: $name
Company: $company
Address: $address
City: $city
State: $state
Zip Code: $zipcode
Country: $country
Website: $website
Phone: $phone
Fax: $fax
Email: $email

Referred to web site: $Referred

CustomerType: $CustomerType

Comments: $Comments

I need help with: $ConsumerHelp

UPC code or Item #: $UPC

Image: $userImage

Kind Regards,

";
    $email_address2 = "$email";
    $subject2 = "Re: Information Inquiry";
    $headers2 = "From: <example@example.com>";
    $messageConsumer2 = str_replace("\r",'',$messageConsumer2); //fixes postfix php bug that double spaces messages



   /******** CONSUMER - NO IMAGE - EMAIL ASC & WEBMASTER  **********/
    $messageOther = "
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Information Inquiry
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

$name has visited the web site and would like some information.
The details they entered on the website are:

Name: $name
Company: $company
Address: $address
City: $city
State: $state
Zip Code: $zipcode
Country: $country
Website: $website
Phone: $phone
Fax: $fax
Email: $email

Referred to web site: $Referred

CustomerType: $CustomerType

Comments: $Comments

I need help with: $ConsumerHelp

UPC code or Item #: $UPC

Kind Regards,

";
    $email_address = "example@example.com";
    $subject = "Information Inquiry";
    $headers = "From: $name <$email>";
    $messageOther = str_replace("\r",'',$messageOther); //fixes postfix php bug that double spaces messages





    /********  CONSUMER - NO IMAGE - EMAIL SENDER **********/
    $messageOther2 = "
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Re: Information Inquiry
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Thank you $name for visiting the web site. We will be using the details you entered to contact you.

Name: $name
Company: $company
Address: $address
City: $city
State: $state
Zip Code: $zipcode
Country: $country
Website: $website
Phone: $phone
Fax: $fax
Email: $email

Referred to web site: $Referred

CustomerType: $CustomerType

Comments: $Comments

I need help with: $ConsumerHelp

UPC code or Item #: $UPC

Kind Regards,

";
    $email_address2 = "$email";
    $subject2 = "Re: Information Inquiry";
    $headers2 = "From: <example@example.com>";
    $messageOther2 = str_replace("\r",'',$messageOther2); //fixes postfix php bug that double spaces messages




$success = mail($email_address, $subject, $message, $headers);
$successConsumer = mail($email_address, $subject, $messageConsumer, $headers);
$successOther = mail($email_address, $subject, $messageOther, $headers);
//conditionally send message2, no need to check success on this one
if (strpos($email,'@aol.com') == false) {
    mail($email_address2, $subject2, $message2, $headers2);
$successConsumer = mail($email_address, $subject, $messageConsumer2, $headers);
$successOther = mail($email_address, $subject, $messageOther2, $headers);
}



if (!$success) {
// What happens when the form does not validate
header("Location: sorry.php");
die ();
} else {
  // Your code here to handle a successful verification
 // header("Location: thanks.php");
    $success;

}
```

?>

**Edit**
I tried replacing the if statement with the code below... I don't get any mail now. Any thoughts?

```
     if ( isset($_POST['CustomerType']) )
{
    if ( $_POST['CustomerType'] === 'Consumer')
    {   
        $success = mail ($headersCoastal, $subjectCoastal, $messageConsumer, $email_address);
        $success = mail ($headersUser, $subjectUser, $messageConsumer2, $email);
       // header("Location: thanks.php");
    }
    else
    {
        $success = mail ($headersCoastal, $subjectCoastal, $messageOther, $email_address);
        $success = mail ($headersUser, $subjectUser, $messageOther2, $email);
       // header("Location: thanks.php");
    }
};
```

**Edit**

```
<?php
// Vars
$name = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'name' );
$email = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'email' );
//$customer = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'customer' );
$company = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'company' );
$address = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'address' );
$city = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'city' );
$state = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'state' );
$zipcode = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'zipcode' );
$country = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'country' );
$website = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'website' );
$phone = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'phone' );
$fax = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'fax' );
$email = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'email' );
$Referred = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'Referred' );
$CustomerType = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'CustomerType' );
$Comments = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'comments' );
$ConsumerHelp = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'ConsumerHelp' );
$UPC = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'UPC' );
$uploaded_file = ($_FILES['uploaded_file']);


$to_asc = 'example@gmail.com';
$to_webmaster = 'example@example.com';
$to_user = $email;
$subject = 'Information Inquiry';
$from = 'ACME WIDGET COMPANY';
$headers = "From: " . $to_asc . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply To: " . $to_asc . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<p>Thank you ' . $name . ' for visiting the Coastal Pet Products web site. We will be using the details you entered to contact you.</p>';

// Check for customer status.
if ( isset( $CustomerType ) )
{
    if ( $CustomerType == 'Consumer')
    {
        $message .= '<p>Name: $name
            </br>Company: $company
            </br>Address: $address
            </br>City: $city
            </br>State: $state
            </br>Zip Code: $zipcode
            </br>Country: $country
            </br>Website: $website
            </br>Phone: $phone
            </br>Fax: $fax
            </br>Email: $email

            </br>Referred to web site: $Referred

            </br>CustomerType: $CustomerType

            </br>Comments: $Comments

            </br>I need help with: $ConsumerHelp

            </br>UPC code or Item #: $UPC';
            header ("Location: thanks.php");
     }
     else
     {
         $message .= '<p>Name: $name
            </br>Company: $company
            </br>Address: $address
            </br>City: $city
            </br>State: $state
            </br>Zip Code: $zipcode
            </br>Country: $country
            </br>Website: $website
            </br>Phone: $phone
            </br>Fax: $fax
            </br>Email: $email

            </br>Referred to web site: $Referred

            </br>CustomerType: $CustomerType

            </br>Comments: $Comments';
            header ("Location: thanks.php");
      }
}
else // Input was not selected at all.
{
    header("Location: sorry.php");
    die ();;
}

// You can look/set other conditions as you go to further assemble a specific message to the user/admins.
// Now back to a chunk that all users see.
//$message .= '<p>Oh well, it\'s all good in the hood!</p>';

//echo $message;


// Mail the message.
 if (mail($to_user, $subject, $message, $headers))
  {
// Mail to user was sent. Now send email to admin(s).
 mail($to_asc, $subject, $message, $headers);
  }
```

**Final Edit**
I was able to get everything working with the code below. The only changes I need to make now are minor, such as setting it so the email that goes to the user says that it is from us, not them. Not a huge deal though! :)

```
<?php
// Vars
$name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
$company = stripslashes($_POST['company']);
$address = stripslashes($_POST['address']);
$city = stripslashes($_POST['city']);
$state = stripslashes($_POST['state']);
$zipcode = stripslashes($_POST['zipcode']);
$country = stripslashes($_POST['country']);
$website = $_POST['website'];
$phone = stripslashes($_POST['phone']);
$fax = stripslashes($_POST['fax']);
$email = stripslashes($_POST['contact']);
$Referred = stripslashes($_POST['referred']);
$CustomerType = stripslashes($_POST['CustomerType']);
$Comments = stripslashes($_POST['comments']);
$ConsumerHelp = stripslashes($_POST['ConsumerHelp']);
$UPC = stripslashes($_POST['UPC']);
$uploaded_file = ($_FILES['uploaded_file']);


$to_asc = 'example@example.com';
$to_webmaster = 'example@example.com';
$to_user = $email;
$subject = 'Information Inquiry';
$from = 'My Company';
$headers = "From: $name <$email>";
//$headers .= "Reply To: " . $to_asc . "\r\n";


$message .= "Thank you, " . $name . ", for visiting the web site. We will be using the details you entered to contact you.";


if ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] == 0) {

         header("Location: thanks.php");
        }

    else {
       // there is a file
        $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]);
        $extension = end($temp);
        $userImage = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"];
        $location = str_replace(' ', '_', $location);
        if ((($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "image/jpg"))
        && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] < 2300000 )
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
          if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["error"] . "<br>";
          } else {
            header("Location: thanks.php");

            if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"])) {
              echo $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            } else {

             $location = "uploads/" . $temp[0].".".time().".".$extension;
             $location = str_replace(' ', '_', $location);
             move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"], $location);
             echo "Stored in: " . $location;
            }
          }
        } else {
          header("Location: sorry.php");
            exit ();
        }
    } 
// Check for customer status.
if ( isset( $CustomerType ) )
{
    if ( $CustomerType == 'Consumer' && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] == 0) )
    {
        $message .= "

                    Name: $name
                    Company: $company
                    Address: $address
                    City: $city
                    State: $state
                    Zip Code: $zipcode
                    Country: $country
                    Website: $website
                    Phone: $phone
                    Fax: $fax
                    Email: $email

                    Referred to web site: $Referred

                    CustomerType: $CustomerType

                    Comments: $Comments

                    I need help with: $ConsumerHelp

                    UPC code or Item #: $UPC";

                header ("Location: thanks.php");
    }
    if ( $CustomerType == 'Consumer' && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] >= 1) )
    {
        $message .= "

                    Name: $name
                    Company: $company
                    Address: $address
                    City: $city
                    State: $state
                    Zip Code: $zipcode
                    Country: $country
                    Website: $website
                    Phone: $phone
                    Fax: $fax
                    Email: $email

                    Referred to web site: $Referred

                    CustomerType: $CustomerType

                    Comments: $Comments

                    I need help with: $ConsumerHelp

                    UPC code or Item #: $UPC

                    Image: http://www.example.com/test/$location";

                header ("Location: thanks.php");
    }
    if ( $CustomerType !== 'Consumer')
{
    $message .= "

                    Name: $name
                    Company: $company
                    Address: $address
                    City: $city
                    State: $state
                    Zip Code: $zipcode
                    Country: $country
                    Website: $website
                    Phone: $phone
                    Fax: $fax
                    Email: $email

                    Referred to web site: $Referred

                    CustomerType: $CustomerType

                    Comments: $Comments";
                header ("Location: thanks.php");
}
}

else // Input was not selected at all.
{
    header("Location: sorry.php");
    die ();;
}

// Mail the message.
if (mail($to_user, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
    // Mail to user was sent. Now send email to admin(s).
    mail($to_asc, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try. I'm not able to test the actual `mail()` function at work. However, when I echo out `$message` i'm getting what I would expect in an email.

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>Email Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm" action="submit.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Customer Form</legend>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Robert Paulson" />
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="robert.paulson@email.com" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <p>Are you a customer?</p>
            <input type="radio" name="customer" id="customerY" value="yes" /><label for="customerY">Yes</label>
            <input type="radio" name="customer" id="customerN" value="no" /><label for="customerN">No</label>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP:** (submit.php)

```
<?php
// Vars
$name = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'name' );
$email = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'email' );
$customer = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'customer' );

$to_asc = 'asc@email.com';
$to_webmaster = 'webmaster@email.com';
$to_user = $email;
$to_isCustomer = 'is.customer@email.com';
$to_isNotCustomer = 'not.customer@email.com';
$subject = 'Information Inquiry';
$from = 'ACME WIDGET COMPANY';
$headers = "From: " . $to_asc . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply To: " . $to_asc . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<p>Hi ' . $name . ', thanks for whatev.</p>';

// Check for customer status.
if ( isset( $customer ) )
{
    if ( $customer == 'yes')
    {
        $message .= '<p>Because you are a valued coustomer, we\'ll respond ASAP!</p>';
    }
    else
    {
        $message .= '<p>Because you are not a coustomer, we\'ll respond sometime - you know, before the house burns down.</p>';
    }

}
else // Input was not selected at all.
{
    $message .= '<p>Because you didn\'t check an option - I don\'t know what to call you.</p>';
}

// You can look/set other conditions as you go to further assemble a specific message to the user/admins.
// Now back to a chunk that all users see.
$message .= '<p>Oh well, it\'s all good in the hood!</p>';

echo $message;


// Mail the message.
if (mail($to_user, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
    // Mail to user was sent. Now send email to admin(s).
    mail($to_asc, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

For example, this is what renders if the user does not select a customer option at all:

`Hi bob, thanks for whatev.
Because you didn't check an option - I don't know what to call you.
Oh well, it's all good in the hood!`

Comment: I still didn't receive any email. It HAS to be something I'm missing or messing up on. :/

Comment: Can you send mail at all?

Comment: I could before I made all of these changes! haha
When it was just one email going to us, and one email going to the user... everything worked fine. When I started adding in all of conditional statements that sent different email depending on what the user selects, it all went down hill! haha

Comment: Okay, I changed the variables at the top from, for example `$name = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'name' );` to `$name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);`, which is the way it was originally set up. This made it so I actually get the email! Yay! I tried it as both a Consumer and not as a Consumer... AND I RECEIVED DIFFERENT MESSAGES AS PLANNED! :) The message was kind of ugly... but I think I can spruce that up a bit. I'll let you know how it goes! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

This might take some re-working, but I would try to cut down the amount of re-doing things.
By that I mean have 1 `mail()` call.

I'm greatly over-simplifying here, but this should give you an idea of what I'm talking about. In essence, you would piece together the message rather than repeat yourself over and over with different mail calls/settings.

**NOTE:** be sure to sanitize all data!

**HTML:**

```
<form action="bla.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="email" name="email" />
    <radio name="customer" value="yes" />
    <radio name="customer" value="no" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$to = '';
$submit = '';
$message = '';
$headers = 'SOME_HEADER_VALUES';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$admin_eamil = 'admin@email.com';

$message .= 'Hello, thanks for whatev.';

if ( isset[$_POST['customer']) )
{
    if ( $_POST['customer'] === 'yes')
    {
        $subject = 'Re: Hi Customer';
        $message .= 'Glad you\'re a customer!'; 
    }
    else
    {
        $subject = 'Re: Meh, whatever';
        $message .= 'We are ignoring you since you are not a customer';
    }
}
else
{
    ...
}

// whatever else conditions you need could go here

...

$message .= 'Glad we got that all cleared up.';

if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) 
{
    mail($admin_eamil, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Comment: I tried working with what you gave me, I'm clearly doing something wrong... I don't get any email now! haha I didn't do it exactly how you had suggested, since I'll have 6 different emails, which go out 2 at a time (depending on how the form is filled out), it just got confusing. I've added an edit to the original post with what I changed. Thank you for responding!

Comment: Ha! That's about the way it works. I will try to get a working example put together today. I didn't test any of the code I had suggested - the theory is good - just not tested. So it is possible it won't work as I have it.